# Apache Spark - Python - How to use range function in Pyspark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

I have some lines of space seperated input data:

```python
Name Company Start_Date End_Date 
Naresh HDFC 2017-01-01 2017-03-31
Anoop ICICI 2017-05-01 2017-07-30
```

I need output as :

```python
Naresh HDFC 2017 01
Naresh HDFC 2017 02
Naresh HDFC 2017 03
Anoop ICICI 2017 05
Anoop ICICI 2017 06
Anoop ICICI 2017 07
```

I have made a textfile of this data and placed this on my Hadoop cluster, and I have written the code but I am having some problem in getting the output. Kindly help.
I am not getting how to extract month from the entries and put them in range function, so I have hard coded in range function a value of 3.

Code:

```python
from pyspark import SparkConf,SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext,Row
from pyspark.sql.types import *
import datetime
sc = SparkContext()
sqlcon = SQLContext(sc)

month_map={'01':1,'02':2,'03':3,'04':4,'05':5,'06':6,'07':7,'08':8,'09':9,
'10':10,'11':11,'12':12}

def get_month(str):
    return datetime.date(int(str[:4]),month_map[str[5:7]],int(str[8:10]))

def parse_line(str):
    match = str.split()
    return (Row(name = match[0],type = match[1],start_date = 
    get_month(match[2]),end_date = get_month(match[3])))


#-----------------create RDD---------------

filepath = '/user/vikasmittal/Innovacer_data.txt'
rdd1 = sc.textFile(filepath)
rdd2 =rdd1.map(parse_line)
for i in range(3):
    rdd3 = rdd2.map(lambda l:(l.name,l.type,l.start_date.year,i))
    print(rdd3.collect())
```

Answer (score 3):

After loading your data transform it into a dataframe and cast `Start_Date` and `End_Date` as dates using either `to_date` or `cast("date")`

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
df = sqlcon\
    .createDataFrame(rdd2, ['Name', 'Company', 'Start_Date', 'End_Date'])\
    .withColumn("Start_Date", psf.to_date("Start_Date"))\
    .withColumn("End_Date", psf.to_date("End_Date"))
df.show()
    +------+-------+----------+----------+
    |  Name|Company|Start_Date|  End_Date|
    +------+-------+----------+----------+
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017-01-01|2017-03-31|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017-05-01|2017-07-30|
    +------+-------+----------+----------+
```

We'll apply a `UDF` to compute the range of dates between `Start_Date` and `End_Date`:

```py
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
def month_range(d1, d2):
    return [d1 + relativedelta(months=+x) for x in range((d2.year - d1.year)*12 + d2.month - d1.month + 1)]

import pyspark.sql.functions as psf
from pyspark.sql.types import *
month_range_udf = psf.udf(month_range, ArrayType(DateType()))
```

We can now apply it to `Start_Date` and `End_Date` and `explode` the array to only get one date per row:

```py
df = df.withColumn("Date", psf.explode(month_range_udf("Start_Date", "End_Date")))
df.show()

    +------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
    |  Name|Company|Start_Date|  End_Date|      Date|
    +------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017-01-01|2017-03-31|2017-01-01|
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017-01-01|2017-03-31|2017-02-01|
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017-01-01|2017-03-31|2017-03-01|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017-05-01|2017-07-30|2017-05-01|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017-05-01|2017-07-30|2017-06-01|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017-05-01|2017-07-30|2017-07-01|
    +------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

We can now extract `year` and `month` from the `Date` column:

```py
res = df.select(
    "Name", 
    "Company", 
    psf.year("Date").alias("year"), 
    psf.month("Date").alias("month")
)
res.show()

    +------+-------+----+-----+
    |  Name|Company|year|month|
    +------+-------+----+-----+
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017|    1|
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017|    2|
    |Naresh|   HDFC|2017|    3|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017|    5|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017|    6|
    | Anoop|  ICICI|2017|    7|
    +------+-------+----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use pyspark's `to_date` function as explained [here](http://takwatanabe.me/pyspark/generated/pyspark.sql.functions.to_date.html).

Just import pyspark.sql.functions.*

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('1997-02-28 10:30:00',)], ['t'])
>>> df.select(to_date(df.t).alias('date')).collect()
[Row(date=datetime.date(1997, 2, 28))]
```

You can extract month as follows :

```
>>> df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('2015-04-08',)], ['a'])
>>> df.select(month('a').alias('month')).collect()
[Row(month=4)]
```